# Compose Column with vertical scrollable modifier not working

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to create a similar-to-scrollview behavior with Jetpack Compose, which should be simple but I find it not working (I can't scroll the Column). I have been following the example from here:
https://github.com/vinaygaba/Learn-Jetpack-Compose-By-Example/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetpackcompose/scrollers/VerticalScrollableActivity.kt#L104

And this is my code:

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .scrollable(
                state = scrollState,
                orientation = Orientation.Vertical
            )
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "This is my first Compose App",
            fontSize = 24.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Light,
            lineHeight = 40.sp,
            color = Color.Black,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 32.dp, start = 24.dp)
        )
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color(0xFF6A0DAD))
                .height(2200.dp))
        {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `Modifier.verticalScroll(scrollState)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was provided by [bylazy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17787605/bylazy) in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75473341/compose-column-with-vertical-scrollable-modifier-not-working/75480034#comment133168611_75473341):

> Try `Modifier.verticalScroll(scrollState)`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33906352)

Comment: @Dez - this **was** the author. They were saying that a comment gave them the solution, and had copied the information from the comment into the answer. This answer is necessarily an answer to the question. There was nothing else the OP could have done here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace:

```
.scrollable(
                state = scrollState,
                orientation = Orientation.Vertical
            )
```

with:

```
.verticalScroll(scrollState)
```